# size of dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, scanf, sizeof

Hi i want to find out size of my dynamic array

```
res=scanf(" %d%1s ",&x,c);
            data[cnt++]=x;
                if(x<0){
                printf("Bad input1.\n");
                return 0;
                }
                if(res != 2){
                printf("Bad input2.\n");
                return 0;
                }
                if(cnt >= size);{
                size *=2;
                data=(int*)realloc(data,size*sizeof(int));
                }           
            }
        printf("Length: %d\n",sizeof(data)/sizeof(int));
        }
```

it keeps telling me size 4 or size 1 even i scanf 5+ numbers ...

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't work with dynamically allocated memory - you need to track the size yourself.

Comment: Thank you but how could i know if i scanf 1 or more inputs or i scanf 0 inputs ? Throught counter ?

Comment: Sure - just count the number of items read, using the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: You already have the size of the buffer. it's exactly `size*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Note that the first semicolon in `if(cnt >= size);{
                size *=2;
                data=(int*)realloc(data,size*sizeof(int));
                }` means that the rest of the code is executed each time you  iterate.  If you have 5 input numbers, you end up with an array able to contain 16 values.

Comment: `res=scanf(" %d%1s ",&x,c);` invokes *Undefined Behavior*, `%1s` requires **2-characters** (e.g. `'A'` and `'\0'` -- the *nul-terminating* character). If you only want one character, use `%c` instead of `%1s`.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the size of the buffer. it's exactly `size*sizeof(int)`.
                    – kaylum

Answer (score 0):

You add elements using cnt as index , at the end it will be exectly the elements count, just print it, though if you want the array length (instead of the number of elements you added) you allready used it to allocate the array: size*sizeof(int).